# Can I use the grill tray in my oven for grilling?

Tags: equipment, oven, grilling, broiling

My oven came with 2 baking trays, and a small tray which looks like a grill (i.e, its got rows of vertical metal strips the same way as a grill does). Can I use this tray for grilling or broiling, and if so, how would I use it?

I.e If I wanted to grill a chicken breast, would I just leave the tray in the oven to heat up, marinate the breast, then put it on the tray and close the oven? Or what would I have to do?

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the tray?  I'm guessing it's part of a [broiler pan](http://www.amazon.com/Smart-Choice-55926-Broiler-Pan/dp/B000YY7N16), and you'll want to use it with its pan as grease and liquid will drop all over the oven otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do - it simulates the high direct heat and then lower, indirect to finish ( like on the real grill with multiple zones):

- Put the 'grill' on the top rack (make sure its not coated or non-stick, that it can take high heat).  (I *do* mean to put a pan under this to catch grease.)
- Turn the oven to broil for a few minutes.
- Prep your chicken.
- Put it in the oven under the broiler for a few minutes (I can't really give you a time here because it depends on thickness and other things), but you're trying to promote that browning and a bit of char like the grill.*
- After its been in a few minutes and browned/charred somewhat, pull it out and quickly flip it and repeat.
- *If your dish isn't fully cooked to your liking*, move the item to the middle rack and turn the heat down some.
- Pull it out when finished and Rest the meat.
- Enjoy

To be honest though, for indoor grilling - I usually preheat the oven to 400, get some grill marks on a cast iron grill pan, and then finish in the oven. Its only when the volume is too much that I do the above method. Cast iron grill pan for a couple of servings has always been much less troublesome than the broiler which can bring items from tasty to ruined in record time *for me*.

---

<sub>*Some people close the oven door here, some don't - its the difference between if you just want to sear it or really start to cook it.  I pretty nearly always close the door, but I'm also the guy who always puts the lid back on the grill.</sub>

Comment: I don't see any option in the oven for turning it to broil, or do I see any broiler?

Comment: @Click Oh, I assumed  you had broil since you specifically mentioned it in your question.  In that case, you could try your highest heat setting and the bottom rack - but it really won't be close to the same.  I'd skip your grill rack then and use the cast iron method - start on the stove, finish in the oven.

Comment: Is there no way to finish it at the stovetop grill?

Comment: @Click - Depends on the particular dish.  I do burgers completely on the stove in the pan (when doing them inside).  Turning very often should generally allow you to cook more in the pan - but its just easier to finish in the oven.