# Can a broiler function as a grill substitute when making kebabs?

Tags: beef, lamb, broiling

When grilling is not option, but broiling is:

**Can a broiler + broiler plate function as a substitute for a grill when making kebabs? If so, what must I do to prevent overcooking beef, lamb and/or veggies?**

Comment: Relevant: http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season9/kabobs/kabob_tran.htm

Comment: Related Question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/17596/can-i-use-the-grill-tray-in-my-oven-for-grilling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing I have to say is kebabs and overcooked are synonymous. If you want all your meats and/or veggies to be cooked right, I would advise you to put each item on it's own skewer so you can take them off as they are finished.

As for a broiler and broiler plate functioning as a substitute for a grill, I would say that it won't be an exact substitute, but you will at least get the high temperature cooking and caramelization you would expect from a grill (you will just be missing the smoke flavor).